# How to calculate the difference between values in two rows of one table using MS Access 2003 SQL? with EXTRA CRITERIA

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

```
Name     ExactDate  Presents
bob      2011        1
bob      2008        2
bob      2012        3
mary     1986        4
mary     2001        5
mary     2012        6
kate     2011        7
kate     2012        8
kate     2013        9
celia    2011       10
celia    1986       11
celia    1972       12
celia    2012       13
celia    1991       14
```

So the goal is we subtract the amount of presents kate got from celia on the same day and out put should be something like the following:

```
Name              ExactDate        Presents
celiaminuskate    2011              3
celiaminuskate    2012              5
```

Thank you so much I am a first time user of access and SQL . and have a data management task required of me at work. so this has really go me stuck 
This is done in ms access 2003 SQL

---

---

HEY SO I GOT THE FIRST PART THERE AND NOW IT GETS HARDER ASSUMING THE DATA SET IS NOW LIKE THIS

```
Name     ExactDate  Presents  Location
bob      2011        1          home
bob      2008        2          school     
bob      2012        3          school
mary     1986        4          school       
mary     2001        5          home
mary     2012        6          homw    
kate     2011        7          home
kate     2012        8          home
kate     2011        9          school 
celia    2011       10          school 
celia    1986       11          school  
celia    1972       12          home
celia    2012       14          home 
celia    2012       13          school
```

So the goal is we subtract the amount of presents kate got from celia on the same year ( but since there are a few different present values for the same year we choose to have priority of home > school....for example celia and kate both recieves presents in 2012 but celia gets both home presents and school presents in 2012 in which case we choose her home present value to do the calculation) and out put should be something like the following:

```
Name              ExactDate        Presents
celiaminuskate    2011              3
celiaminuskate    2012              6
```

Comment: Your question title ('Please help a summer student for a task requested of them at work. beginner at data management') is inappropriate - you should describe the problem, not who you are.

Comment: For 2012, shouldn't it be 13-8 = 5?

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler I have changed it to more suitably describe the quesion.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth its my frist time working with SQL and access so after doing research for two days i had a subquery nested inside a query and it took forever to run. I never actualyl got results. usually when i google. I was only able to find parts and btis of the problem liek adding entries in a column or jsut finding same values in a column and I incorrectly put these actiosn together resulting in them not working >.> In summary I'm a complete noob who still ahs much much to learn .

Comment: and yes @Tom H. it most definately should be 5 thanks!

Comment: @Lizzy - It's good that you've explained what you tried, but you should probably edit the question to include that information and preferably the exact query which you've tried to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    'celiaminuskate' AS [NAME],
    T1.[date] AS [EXACT DATE],
    T1.presents - T2.presents AS [PRESENTS DIFF]
FROM
    Some_Table T1
INNER JOIN Some_Table T2 ON
    T2.[name] = 'kate' AND
    T2.[date] = T1.[date]
WHERE
    T1.[name] = 'celia'
ORDER BY
    T1.[date]
```

A couple of suggestions since you're new to SQL:

1. Try to avoid using keywords, like "date" for column names
2. Your "date" column looks like a year, not a date. It should be named appropriately and you should make sure that it's the correct data type.

Since it sounds like the version of Access that you're using doesn't support the now standard `JOIN` syntax, here is another query which should be equivalent:

```
SELECT
    'celiaminuskate' AS [NAME],
    T1.[date] AS [EXACT DATE],
    T1.presents - T2.presents AS [PRESENTS DIFF]
FROM
    Some_Table T1, Some_Table T2
WHERE
    T1.[name] = 'celia' AND
    T2.[name] = 'kate' AND
    T2.[date] = T1.[date]
ORDER BY
    T1.[date]
```

`T1` and `T2` in this query are simply aliases for the tables in the `FROM` clause so that you can distinguish them.

If you're trying to put the results into another table then you will need this to be part of an `INSERT` statement. Or, with Access you might be able to use a query to generate a table as part of some wizard. I'm afraid that I don't have a copy handy to give more specifics. In any case, here is what the `INSERT` statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO Some_New_Table (name, exactdate, presentsdiff)
SELECT ...
```

(The ellipsis just means to use the query as I have it up above)

Comment: thank you for your reply . So i ran into some other problems that werent expected. the JOIN expression is not supported was the error message >.> ...is taht normal for access 2003? Should i request my supervisor to have a later version of access or is there any way to fix this problem? thanks!

Comment: SELECT     
'celiaminuskate' AS Name,     
T2.ExactDate AS ExactDate,     
T2.Presents–T1.Presents AS PresentsDiff
FROM     
 T2 
INNER JOIN T1 ON     
T1.Name= 'kate' AND     
T1.ExactDate = T2.ExactDate 
WHERE     T2.Name = 'celia' 
ORDER BY     
T2.ExactDate

Comment: that was the exact code i put in the sql view t2 and t1 are interchanged because when importing data i named them opposite lol.

Comment: I don't have Access 2003 handy. It may be that it doesn't support the SQL standard `JOIN` syntax. In that case, you can put both tables in the `FROM` clause (comma-separated) and put all of the criteria in the `WHERE` clause. This makes certain `OUTER JOIN` operations impossible, but in this case it shouldn't make a difference. If I have a chance to check this on Access 2003 I'll change my answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: on my database window it also says access 2000 file format i hope that has nothign to do with it

Comment: If possible Tom could you show me what to do for the "put both tables in the FROM clause (comma-separated) and put all of the criteria in the WHERE clause. " if doign it that way is a good idea?

Comment: The first table is T1 second table or selected data will be eventually outputted to T2? Thansk everyone for their comments so far!!
Also this part here i meant my origianl data is in T1 and i want to put the result in T2 . I'm not sure if "T1.presents - T2.presents AS [PRESENTS DIFF] " meant u put my original data into two seperate charts before using this code or?    sry for delaing with an absolute beginner like me >.>

Comment: Thank you Tom that was exactly what i needed and everything is workign fine and dandy now!

Comment: Since you're new to the site... be sure to select one of the answers as the "correct" answer so that people in the future with the same problem can easily find it.

Comment: Alright! and Tom there is some extra criteria on the question now if you wanted to take a look at it

Comment: so it did end up working. the code you gave me. but it does it twice for some weird reason and i end up with two rows for each calculation lol

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a `self-join`, because you are comparing rows from the same table.
Below we join table1 to itself using simular dates, but different names.
A more realistic answer would use unique row_ids instead of names.
Next we tell the database that we want only `celia`'s rows in part1 and only `kate`'s rows in part2.

```
SELECT 'celiaminuskate' AS useless_filler
       , a.[date] AS whendidthishappen
       , (celia.presents - kate.presents) AS outcome
FROM table1 AS kate
INNER JOIN table1 AS celia ON (a.[date] = b.[date] and a.name <> b.name)
WHERE celia.name = 'celia' and kate.name = 'kate'
```

Note that `date` is a reserved word and you will need to enclose it in square brackets `[]`

Comment: I think you need to reverse the subtraction.

Comment: @Jonathan, I renamed the tables kate and celia (instead of a en b) and flipped things around, hope celia is not too angry with me for stealing her toys.

Comment: @Johan hi sorry I'm a bit confused u renamed the tables celia and Kate?   like u renamed my originall data table and the one i want to input two or did u seperate my data in table 1 into two seperate tables and then use this code      thanks

Comment: If you join a table with itself you **must** rename the tables using an alias, SQL demands it. So I renamed the part of the table with celia's presents in it to `celia` and likewise for `kate`. You can choose any name as an alias (as long as it's not a reserved word). So **yes** to `or did u seperate my data in table 1 into two seperate tables?`

Answer (score 2):

The key to answering this is a self-join:

```
SELECT 'Celia - Kate' AS tag, C.ExactDate, C.Presents - K.Presents
  FROM (SELECT ExactDate, Presents FROM AnonymousTable WHERE Name = 'celia') AS C
  JOIN (SELECT ExactDate, Presents FROM AnonymousTable WHERE Name = 'kate')  AS K
    ON C.ExactDate = K.ExactDate
 ORDER BY C.Date;
```

Comment: `date` is a reserved word, enclose it in square brackets `[date]`

Comment: @Johan: I've adjusted the answer to the amended question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer.  Hey thank you so much for your input it sounds like it should work but when i try to code after ofcourse putting in name of table etc . It gives me "syntax error in FROM clause"

Comment: @Lizzy: that may be because Access 2003 does not support the 'query in the FROM clause' notation that I used.  Most of the SQL DBMS do, but some supported it quicker than others.  If this doesn't work in Access 2003, then you lose the pleasant symmetry of the answer.  I don't have Access to play with (AFAIK).

Comment: @Jonathan  no worries and thank you for your help! I'm currently trying out the other answers

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'celiaminuskate', p1.exactdate, p1.presents - p2.presents
FROM presents p1 JOIN presents p2 ON p1.exactdate = p2.exactdate
WHERE p1.name = 'celia' AND p2.name = 'kate'
```

Comment: -1 For using implicit `where` joins. They are a bad idea and should be replaced by explicit joins to avoid confusion, accidental cross joins and undue nostalgia for 1989.

Comment: @Johan - You are right, I changed the query to use an explicit join instead.

Comment: thanks for your effort! turns out my access did not support JOIN lol >.> but Tom H. helped me figure out a way.